# Pivot query that shows the average amount spent per customer for each month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get better at writing pivot queries by writing one against the [Sakila Sample Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) that shows the average amount spent per customer for each month.  I've got the basic query down, but I'm not sure how to turn it into a pivot query.

Here's the SQL for that query:

```
SELECT
    payment.amount AS amount,
    customer.customer_id AS customer_id,
    customer.last_name AS last_name, 
    customer.first_name AS first_name,
    FORMAT ( rental.rental_date, 'MMM' ) _Month,
    avg(amount) over ( PARTITION BY customer.customer_id ) avg_rental_amt
FROM
    customer INNER JOIN
 rental
 ON customer.customer_id = rental.customer_id INNER JOIN
 payment
 ON payment.rental_id = rental.rental_id AND
    payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

And here is the above query with results in my Navicat database development and admin client:

[image: Query that shows the average amount spent per customer for each month]

Anyone know how to convert these results to a pivot query so that the columns from left to right are customer_id, last_name, first_name, Jan, Feb, ...Dec, avg_rental_amt, in either MySQL or SQL Server?   I'd like the results to look something like this if possible:

```
customer_id last_name   first_name  Jan  Feb...Dec    avg_rental_amt
505         ABNEY       RAFAEL      4.9  2.9   3.4    4.65
504         ADAM        NATHANIEL   5.3  4.4   5.2    4.77
36          ADAMS       KATHLEEN    .9  .9     3.1    3.43
etc...
```

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: *how to convert these results to a pivot query* Like always when the list of columns is static. Grouping + conditional aggregating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.last_name, c.first_name,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.rental_date) =  1 THEN p.amount END) as avg_rental_january,
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.rental_date) =  2 THEN p.amount END) as avg_rental_feb,
    ...
    AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.rental_date) = 12 THEN p.amount END) as avg_rental_december,
    AVG(p.amount) avg_rental
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN rental r ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id 
INNER JOIN payment p ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id AND p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.last_name, c.first_name
```

This syntax should work in both SQL Server and MySQL.

Note that this averages together rentals of the same customer *over different years* - as in your original query. This may, or may not be what you want. If not, you would need to adapt the conditional expressions for your exact need.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically manage returning results by applying conditional aggregation

in **SQL Server (<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7db19cb73634c1e2b8df8b32b92bd37b)</kbd>) :**

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL
 SELECT n + 1 FROM t WHERE n + 1 <= 12
)
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.rental_date)=',n,
                                         ' THEN r.amount END) "',
                                         FORMAT ( DATEADD( month , n , -1 ), 'MMM' ),
                                         '"'), ',') 
  FROM t;

SET  @query = 
       CONCAT(
              'SELECT c.customer_id AS customer_id,' , @cols , 
              '       , AVG(r.amount) AS avg_rental_amt ',
              '  FROM customer c
                 JOIN rental r
                   ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
                 JOIN payment p
                   ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
                  AND p.customer_id = c.customer_id
                GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.last_name, c.first_name');

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

in **My SQL (<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a453a609390a03eee3e975e22fc64126)</kbd>):**

```
SET @query = NULL;
SET @cols = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(                 
             CONCAT(
                    'AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.rental_date)=', n,
                            ' THEN r.amount END) AS "',
                           DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT('0000-',LPAD(n,2,0),'-00'), '%b'),
                           '"'
                    )
       )
  INTO @cols
  FROM
  (
   SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n
     FROM information_schema.tables 
     JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) AS iter ) nn
  WHERE n <= 12;

SET  @query = 
       CONCAT(
              'SELECT c.customer_id AS customer_id,' , @cols , 
              '       , AVG(r.amount) AS avg_rental_amt ',
              '  FROM customer c
                 JOIN rental r
                   ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
                 JOIN payment p
                   ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
                  AND p.customer_id = c.customer_id
                GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.last_name, c.first_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```